# Why doesn't NAnt generate a bootstrapper file after calling MSBuild on a project?

Tags: msbuild, wix, nant, bootstrapper

I have a project with this in its MSBuild script:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <GenerateBootstrapper ApplicationFile="MyApp.msi" ApplicationName="My App" BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)" OutputPath="$(OutputPath)" Culture="en-US" CopyComponents="true" ComponentsLocation="HomeSite" Path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper" />
  </Target>
```

If I run the project in visual studio, that gets run after the build and a setup.exe bootstrapper file is created in my bin/debug directory. However, if I build that same project (a WiX project, if that matters) under NAnt, everything gets built in the output directory that NAnt specifies, except the bootstrapper file. Nothing is being built in the project's bin/debug directory when I build it under NAnt, so the setup.exe file doesn't seem to be getting built, even there. I don't think that the AfterBuild step is even being run.

How can I generate this bootstrapper file under NAnt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to specify the variable OutputPath in my NAnt script: